# Single Word Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms, methodology

How to use machine learning algorithms to predict class of single values/words ?

```
 Use-case : I have a list of different labels and their values.

 eg : 
 Labels [Colour, Height, Weight, Location, Width etc]
 Values [red, green, 10 cm, 80 kg, usa, uk etc]
```

Now given a sentence like "color red height 10 usa 80 kg", what is the best way to tokenize them as Labels and Values?

```
Input : color red height 10 usa 80 kg"
Output:
     Labels [color, height]
     Values [red, 10, usa, 80kg]
```

Note : there is no delimiters in the given sentence, 
       values and labels are not fixed,
       values can occur without label in a sentence.

Once Values and Labels are detected,need to map them as pairs.

```
{
  color  : red
  height : 10
  weight : 80 kg
  location : usa,uk
}
```

Currently I am using a lookup list for mapping labels and values and this list need to be updated whenever a new label or value is found. Is this the best way to solve ?

Can this problem be solved using ML ?

Comment: In your example the value always follows the label, except in the case of the location. Can this kind of assumption be made about all the input sentences? because if yes you would almost only need a list of labels.

Comment: Position and order can change. Not fixed. Also there can be new labels and values

Comment: Imagine you have to explain how to do the task to a human employee who doesn't have any knowledge or expertise, what would you ask them to do exactly?

Comment: Yes, Currently I am using a lookup list for mapping labels and values and this list need to be updated whenever a new label or value is found.. is there any other way?

Comment: If there's no indication in the text which helps to know which word is a label and which a word is a value, I don't see any other way. Training a supervised classifier could work but you would need to annotate sentences so it would probably be more work than updating a lookup list.

Comment: The only indicator I can think of would be the syntactic category of the word: in your example labels are nouns, values are adjectives or numericals and the location is a proper name. If this can be generalized maybe you can automatize the process of updating the lookup list.

Comment: @Erwan : Training a supervised classifier could work but you would need to annotate sentences  - What can be the features in that case ?

Comment: Well, that's why I was asking earlier how you would describe the task to a human: the idea is to rely on the indicators that a human would use. apparently the syntactic categories of the words might be useful, but I don't know if it's enough.